# PF on macOS Sierra doesn't seem to be reading ApplicationFirewall

Tags: macos, firewall, macos-sierra, pf

I have PF working but when I start/restart the system the postfix 'master' program asks me if I want to grant permission to it to accept connections from the internet.
 Now, permission is set in the SystemFirewall, that you set up through preferences.
However, I also have my own ruleset in /etc/pf.anchors/local.rules that pf loads at startup.

```
#
# com.apple anchor point
#
int_if  = "en0"
lan_net = "192.168.0.0/24"

set skip on lo0
tcp_services = "{ ssh, smtp, domain, www, pop3, auth, pop3s }"
udp_services = "{ domain }"


scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
#
```

So I start pfctl in the plist with pfctl -ef /etc/pf.anchors/local.rules

Everything is running fine with this - except for the postfix master. Which tells me that pfctl is not reading the 250.ApplicationFirewall/* anchor - which should be the ... ApplicationFirewall rules.

This

```
sudo pfctl -a com.apple -sr
```

returns

```
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
anchor "200.AirDrop/*" all
anchor "250.ApplicationFirewall/*" all
```

Could it be that I shouldn't run the Application Firewall at the same time as the pf controller?
Or, how do I tell pf rules to actually read the ApplicationFirewall rules?

Comment: If you still have this problem, could you include your local.rules within your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 2 Firewalls

On MacOS you have 2 independant firewalls:
1st one is working at protocol level and is Packet Filter from OpenBSD.
It is activated with `pfctl -e -f pf_configuration_file`.

2nd one is `ApplicationFirewall` and is working at the socket level, but as a preliminary step enable PF.
It is activated with the GUI `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Firewall Options…`.

These 2 firewalls **can work alone or together**.
But the GUI of MacOS brings the 2 up together.

The application firewall is loading its own set of PF rules
anchored on:

```
/com.apple/250.ApplicationFirewall
```

unfortunately, the source of this set of rules is not accessible.

Then these 2 firewall should be working perfectly well independantly.
Unfortunatey the GUI of the application firewall is starting PF on its own and this is not documented.

I think the work from Apple is not finished on these 2 layers of firewall. My best advice to get out of this undocumented GUI is to make a complete local copy of the tree:

```
/com.apple/250.ApplicationFirewall
```

### 1 Missing tool

It is very difficult to have a correct vision of the whole set of rules applied at a given time with PF and a tree of anchors.

There is no standard tool other than the `pfctl` to analyse security problems.

Here is a tool you can use to help you in this process:

[pfdump](https://gist.github.com/dazuelos/3978acf5c3193ce78f3217ff8c061a29)

To analyze your problem I advise you to use `nmap` (see `Brew` or `Macports`) to check that your `master` is locally reachable on `25/tcp`.